# Get the coordinates of the intersection between a line and 3d model

Tags: geometry, mathematics, coordinates, intersection

I'm new to Blender. I want to know if there's a way to get the coordinates of the intersection point between a given line and a 3D model, just like the picture below. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible. How would you like this vector served up? From a script?  In Geometry Nodes? What are you going to use it for?

Comment: you can search for "raycast" - which exists for python but for geometry nodes as well as for animation nodes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "manual" method:

select the line and sbdivide it in edit mode, select the newly created vertex and press Ctrl G to assign it to a new vertex group.

Add a shrinkwrap modifier, limit its action to the new vertex group, change its wrap method to "Project" and snap mode to "On surface".

Enable "Negative" and "Positive" and pick your solid mesh as Target.

In object mode Apply the modifier.

Now you can select the vertex in the line and read its coordinates in the Transform tab of the "N" properties panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out how to do that using code!